# Ruby Simple Database Migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am very new to Ruby and need to do a simple database migration. I have
a table in my database called data_sources and I need to update record
id 3 field systems from Fusion to Fusion,Matrix.

I had ruby auto create the file but then I just got lost.

```
class UpdateDataSourcesGlvarSystems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
  end
end
```

Thanks for the help,

Kane

Comment: Do you mean you need to update an attribute field systems in your existing record id 3?

Comment: If you're just trying to fix a mistake you made for a single row, why not just use an appropriate front end for your database and edit it directly? What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Is this a change to the contents of a cell? Rails migrations are more for changing the structure of your table, not adding data to them.

Comment: as i understand, do you want to migrate it ? Change column name or data ?

Comment: You shouldn't need a migration for this. You should be able to update the record directly from the Rails console. See Diego's answer.

Answer (score 0):

if it's just a unique task to do, use rails console:

```
$ rails c


fix = MyModel.find 3
fix.data_sources = "Fusion,Matrix"
fix.save
```